# Modifying Ubuntu Budgie menu items

Tags: 17.04, menu, budgie

So I know I can modify the super icon, but at the same time I find it rather hectic to have all my wine programs creating separate categories and all that.  Is there a way I can modify my budgie menu so that I can put say, Hot Wheels Velocity X in the Games category with mednaffe and extreme tux racer.

Comment: https://github.com/budgie-desktop/budgie-desktop/issues/789

Comment: That worked a bit, except now I have duplicate entries of menu folders.  For example, when I press the super key I see Internet twice

Comment: I've no experience with Budgie or I would have posted an answer.  Just was curious enough to google it.  I've worked with LXDE menus extensively.